# iPhone SDK "loading" on Titanium Developer

Tags: iphone, loading, titanium, appcelerator

I have tried this question on the site of Titanium and several tweets to their account, but they either ignore me or refuse to answer.

I want to start using their framework, but for some reason the iPhone SDK is always "loading" when in the "TEST & PACKAGE" tab.

Have you guys found a fix for this? I have:

- Snow Leopard 10.6.3
- Titanium Developer 1.2.1
- iPhone SDK 3.2
- All the certificates "blah blah" from Apple because I am able to test and deploy apps on my device using XCode.

Help please :)

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling the SDK after installing Titanium?

Comment: I even formatted my PC and no luck

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you have a name with non-ASCII characters? 
There is a bug regarding developer certificates with non-ASCII characters in them.
I've filed a bug report, to Appcelerator's Lighthouse site:

My name has a character with umlaut (ö) which prevents prereq.py from doing what it should. Titanium only says "Loading..." in the SDK version select box.

The patch attached to the page, which changes json parser into simplejson, helps the python script to pass. I run it in console and get the expected output:

'{"wwdr": true,"ipad": false,"sdks": ["3.1","3.1.2","3.1.3"],"iphone_dev_name": ["Björn Söderqvist (XXXXXXXXXX)"],"iphone_dist_message": "Missing iPhone Distribution Certificate","wwdr_message": null,"itunes_message": null,"itunes": true,"iphone_dev_message": null,"iphone_dev": true,"iphone_dist": false,"itunes_version": "9.0.3"}'

Titanium app still reads the output wrong though.

It works if I copy-paste the console output of patched prereq.py like so:
(line 877 of packaging.js)

var d = '{"wwdr": true,"ipad": false,"sdks": ["3.1","3.1.2","3.1.3"],"iphone_dev_name": ["Björn Söderqvist (XXXXXXXXXX)"],"iphone_dist_message": "Missing iPhone Distribution Certificate","wwdr_message": null,"itunes_message": null,"itunes": true,"iphone_dev_message": null,"iphone_dev": true,"iphone_dist": false,"itunes_version": "9.0.3"}'

https://appcelerator.lighthouseapp.com/projects/32238/tickets/646-iphone-sdk-problem-with-non-ascii-characters-in-development-certificate

Unfortunately, the link I refer to in the post does not work anymore. The suggested patch was to do the following to prereq.py:

Line 8

```
#import json, run, tempfile, codecs
import poorjson, run, tempfile, codecs
```

Line 139 (replace last line of check_for_package() with this)

```
print poorjson.PoorJSON().dump(props)
```

Let me know if you need more specific information.

Comment: I was able to solve this appcelerator, you were right... and my name "Raúl" was causing problems

Comment: Appcelerator moved all their tickets into JIRA, but didn't update all their links that were referencing Lighthouse.  Here's the relevant ticket: http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-646