# Titanium Developer: iPhone SDK "loading" never finishes on mobile SDK 1.6.2 and 1.7.0 RC1

Tags: ios, macos, titanium

I've got the famous problem that Titanium never finishes loading the prerequisites on OSX 10.6.7 .
XCode version is 4.0.1 and Titanium Developer version is 1.2.2.

executing python prereq.py project. gives this output:

> {"wwdr": true,"iphone_dist_name": ["COMPANY"],"sdks": ["4.3","4.2","4.1","4.0","3.2"],"iphone_dev_name": ["Martin Luther (XXXXXXXXXXX)"],"iphone_dist_message": null,"wwdr_message": null,"itunes_message": null,"itunes": true,"iphone_dev_message": null,"iphone_dev": true,"iphone_dist": true,"ipad": true,"itunes_version": "10.0"}

I even tried the umlaut-patch mentioned here without success (there are no Umlauts anyways):
[iPhone SDK "loading" on Titanium Developer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2610951/iphone-sdk-loading-on-titanium-developer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This problem doesn't occur if I start Titantium Developer via Bash.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's not the answer you want but have you tried [TiStudio](http://preview.appcelerator.com/studio/)?

Comment: Yeah, that works. Thanks a lot.
I can't mark this question answered so since using TiStudio is just a workaround.

Comment: fair enough, I'll update my answer if I figure it out but I've never had this issue so I've never really had a shot at trying to fix it...